# Enhancing current Javascript show and hide function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

so I currently have this function in javascript.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#type').on('change', function(e) {
        alert($(this).val())
        if ($(this).val() == '190452') { // Name1
            $('#first_name').parent().parent().hide();
        } else if($(this).val() == '105561'){ //Name2
            $('#surname').parent().parent().hide();
        } else if($(this).val() == '105581'){ //Name3
            $('#company_name').parent().parent().hide();
        } else if($(this).val() == '105601'){ // Name4
            $('#company_name').parent().parent().hide();
        }
    });
})
```

This is working fine, the alert is only there for testing purposes. However, there are ways in which I wish to enhance it but I'm not entirely sure how.

Here is the scenario, I have an drop down list (options) with 4 Ids on it (as above) and the 5th option being "Please select" The scenario I want is as follows

- Please select - show no form
- name 1 - show certain parts of form
- name 2 - As above
- name 3 - As above
- name 4 - As above.

The problem at the moment is, if I select name 1 for example, it will remove a row called "first_name" however, if I then go to select name 2-4 that row is lost forever although I need it to return. Without listing ALL the (shows) as well as the (hides) is there a more efficient way to make sure, when you select another option that it doesn't hide that specific row. It will return?

I have been looking at (.is(':visible')) but I am not entirely sure how I could implement it in this format, any pointers would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery has a [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function, which may give you the functionality you're looking for.

Also, instead of using `.parent().parent()` you could use the [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) selector, that would clean up a bit of your redundancy.

Comment: Ah ok, that is useful. Any idea on how to get the rows back with out stating they need to be (show)

Comment: Thanks RockHopper, toggle seems to be good when selecting the same option again, it will appear.

Would I need the form to do some kind of refresh when other options are selected?

Comment: I haven't seen you form, but you shouldn't, .toggle() should just toggle back and forth on every click event.

Comment: Thank you, it took some working around but it now works.